# Virtualtreeview for Borland C++ Builder 6

Tags: c++builder

I downloaded the VirtualTreeView component for Borland C ++ Builder 6.0 and I'm trying to learn how to use it. Unfortunately I can not find any code for this compiler that serves as an example and I am based on a Delphi code that I have given.

I have created a project with a single form that contains only one TVirtualStringTree. I am using this code to try to understand how it works.

In the CPP:

```
void __fastcall TForm1 :: FormCreate (TObject * Sender)
{
    AnsiString cLiteral;
    PTrecBase pRecData;
    PVirtualNode Node;

    VST-> BeginUpdate ();
    VST-> Clear ();
    VST-> NodeDataSize = sizeof (TRecBase);

    for (int nItem = 0; nItem <10; nItem ++)
    {
        cLiteral = "Node" + IntToStr (nItem);
        Node = VST-> AddChild (NULL);
        pRecData = (PTrecBase) VST-> GetNodeData (Node);
        pRecData-> Literal = cLiteral;

        for (int nSub = 0; nSub <5; nSub ++)
        {
            Node = getNodeDondeInsert (cLiteral);
            Node = VST-> AddChild (Node);
            pRecData = (PTrecBase) VST-> GetNodeData (Node);
            pRecData-> Literal = cLiteral + "Sub" + IntToStr (nSub);
        }
    }
    VST-> EndUpdate ();
}
```

In the H:

```
class TForm1: public TForm
{
__published: // IDE-managed Components
     TVirtualStringTree * VST;
     void __fastcall FormCreate (TObject * Sender);
private: // User declarations
public: // User declarations
     __fastcall TForm1 (TComponent * Owner);
};

struct TRecBase
{
     AnsiString Literal;
};

typedef TRecBase * PTrecBase;
```

However I can not get the literal that I want to show. Only this is shown:
[image]

And I do not know what I'm doing wrong so that you do not see the literals that I'm defining. Does anyone have a code for C ++ Builder that can guide me? Thank you.

Comment: Off topic question: Why are you using C++Builder 6, instead of, say, the free C++Builder Community? C++B6 is from 2001, whereas Community is very recent and far more complete.

Comment: Simply because with more modern versions of Builder I am not able to understand myself. I installed the XE2 and XE3 versions but I was unable to take out even a simple project. On the other hand, he was unaware of the existence of a free version of Builder.

Answer (score 1):

You are storing string data for each node, but you have no event handlers assigned to the TreeView, particularly `OnGetText`, to supply those strings to the TreeView when it is being rendered. This is a *virtual* control, you have to supply it with data when it asks you for it.

There is a [C++Builder demo](https://github.com/Virtual-TreeView/Virtual-TreeView/tree/master/Demos/CBuilderMinimal) available on VirtualTreeView's GitHub repository

Answer (score -1):

Thanks for your reply.

The code that you have indicated to me I have already tried it and I am not able to understand it because I can not find in which part of it it is necessary to indicate the literal of the node. The attached image is the result I get with that example code.

[Form CBMininal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sllYe.jpg)

As you can see the result is practically the same as in the image that I went up yesterday. What I'm most sorry about is that even though I searched, I did not find any sample code for this component for Borland C ++.

What's more: If I run the example with the debugger, the same thing happens to me as with my code.

In my code when I execute the line *pRecData->Literal = cLiteral;* I can see in the debugger that it has the calculated values (**Node 0**, **Node 1**, etc.) and in the example, when this one is executed (*Text = Data->Caption;*) I can see that both Text and Data->Caption contain the value, for example, **Level 0, Index 5** but this literal is not shown in the TVirtualStringTree.

Comment: A virtual component is something that doesn't store its own data, but queries the user for the data it must display. In Delphi this is generally done in event handlers. In the *OnGetText* handler you must provide the text for the given node. Of course you must provide different texts for different nodes.

Comment: FWIW, this "answer" should be a comment. It is not an answer.

Comment: If it refers to me: Actually it should be a comment, but as in the comments I can not (or do not know) include images for that reason I put it as an answer.

Comment: Then post a link. This is not a valid answer. This should be a comment only.

Comment: «In the OnGetText handler you must provide the text for the given node»

I have understood that the text of each node must be indicated in the OnGetText event but even in the example that I have been suggested, and that I had already tried, I do not see how to do it. That's why I was commenting before that executing with the debugger when I get to that event I can see the value (for example Node 0, index 1) but nevertheless in the object the Node value is simply shown. I do not know if it will be necessary to modify some property of the object.

Comment: Okay. I just found the reason why the definite literal was not shown; I was misusing a variable in the OnGetText event. Thanks everyone for your help.